# Access iCloud mail on iPad without setting up device

Tags: ipad, icloud

How can I view iCloud.com/#mail on an ipad without setting it up on the device? I want to check my emails on an ipad that isn't mine. I can normally access it on a PC but don't have access to one of them right now. Whenever I go to the website it just shows me the setup icloud on this device screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the page www.icloud.com recognizes Safari on iPad and iPhone as a mobile iOS browser and then presents the page with the setup message.
But you could try to access the page with [Google's chrome](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/chrome/id535886823?mt=8). It has an option to open pages in a desktop version. That might help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Photon Browser (free app) which allows you to connect to Flash sites.

Go to iCloud.com.

Tap the Lightning bolt in the upper right of the Photon screen.

Sign in.

Tap mail.

Tap gear icon on lower left of mail window.

Tap "vacation".

More here: https://help.apple.com/icloud/#/mm6b1a04d1